# Is availability of video pornography a main reason of sexual crimes in developing and under-developing countries?

Tags: sexuality, criminology, sexual-abuse, pornography

I think it is easiest to google search for a porn video than any other thing. What I notice is that whenever a sexual criminal is caught and when Police search for his belongings, almost every time Police find a pen drive of very high storage full of pornography or the criminal's computer/s is/are filled with excessive porn **videos**. One more important thing to notice is that often the victims quote that the criminal/s made them to watch (many a times the victims are not adult) those porn videos and to mimic what's happening in it.

[This question here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6656/56944) claims that sexual offenses have gone down with easy availability of porn, but that's the case (if  true at all) in developed nations where the punishment for sexual offenses are very strict, but in developing countries where Police and Courts are over-busy with the matters of Governmental corruptions and crimes sexual offenses many a times go unnoticed.

I read somewhere that we feel excited and aroused when we see an unclad body's image because our brains tell us that it's time for reproduction and the person in the image is a right candidate for the reproduction (we are evolved like that). But in the pornographic videos things are different, and they cause people to go mad and imitate the acts done in the video.

All right, let's have a look at some so called notable claims: [In this link](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/bhopal/madhya-pradesh-home-minister-calls-for-ban-on-porn-sites/articleshow/63884288.cms) we find a governmental minister saying:

> that pornography is incitement to rape

Pornography is banned in China, and [this link](https://qz.com/1001366/how-the-chinese-watch-porn-on-chinas-censored-internet/) says

> Pornography is strictly forbidden in China. Those who produce, disseminate, or sell “obscene materials” could be jailed for life, according to the country’s criminal law.

So, you see production of pornography is a crime in China. Not only China but other countries too see Pornography as crime, [Philippines's ISPs banned](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-38637003) pornography by saying

> the sites have been blocked because of anti-child-pornography laws.

Rich countries know that they, ISPs and porn industries make a lot of money by pornographic sites so they don't completely ban it (just like government realized that imposing high tax on alcoholic beverages would benefit them more than prohibiting the alcohol) but they know and when the truth.

Comment: The last sentence is precisely the reverse of what this site requires: the _question_ has to provide the claim by a notable personality, the _answers_ provide support or refutation of it by actual experts. Have a look at the [Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users) which hopefully explains this a bit better than I can in a short comment.

Comment: @IMSoP Where one can go if he wants some notable claims on a matter which media and general public discusses. To say the least, in many developing countries pornographic sites are banned (you can easily find what are these countries).

Comment: Here [is a notable claim](https://youtu.be/pTrxxqtaIyg), if that’s what the site wants. But again it’s in my regional language (but the title should suffice the rules of this SE) and I don’t think saying the same thing by Chief Minister of Bihar (a state of India) and by general public should have any difference.

Comment: "Notable" absolutely doesn't need to mean "rich and powerful", but the way you wrote the question so far didn't mention _anybody_ making the claim. If you click [edit] under the question, you can improve it  by showing that this is something people are claiming, and that you want to know if there is good evidence for it (which is what this site is for).

Comment: "almost every time Police find a pen drive of very high storage full of pornography" - [citation needed] Is it that *you* have spotted this a few times when it's reported in the press or do you have an actual study demonstrating that in almost all cases the perpetrator of a sexual offence had large quantities of pornography stored and how that correlates to such instances of stored pornography in the general public?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I spotted it almost every time. Even the my school eve-teasers and amateur black-mailers have a good collection of porn in their computers and mobiles. General public who stores large amount of porn is always at the verge of being acting out in an unacceptable way.

Comment: "The plural of anecdote is not data." Unless you have something more concrete to back it up, the entire premise of your question is in doubt.

Comment: Voting to close. The question asks if porn causes sex crimes only in poorer countries, but does not link to a notable claim saying that. It also seems to exist to push a particular point of view rather than to actually ask a question.

Comment: @PaulJohnson You may do as you wish, but don’t attribute to me what I didn’t say. I never used the term “poorer countries”, there is a large difference in what I used and what you used.

Comment: OK, s/poorer/developing and under developing/ . Doesn't change anything.

Comment: Well, we got a lot of questions that look like possible dupes of this: [Does pornography “entice sexual violence against women”?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8373/11643) / [Are youths that watch violent X-rated material 6 times more likely to force others sexually?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/22234/11643) / [Is regularly viewing internet pornography unhealthy?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/27045/11643) / [Is the increasing availability of high speed internet pornography reducing sex crime rates?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6656/11643)

Comment: Then there's the issue of the question and title asking about some relation to "developing" countries, but no claim presented that seems to match that. I think we need to focus this question so that claims match the title and it's not a dupe.

Comment: Yes, you may have multiple SE accounts, but the two are prohibited from interacting in any way. Since you've asked as "Knight admires chappo", you'll have to put your "Knight" account away for a bit.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately I don't have a nice thesis to link you to - My Ex GF tried to do her PHD on this (Protective factors on the exposure of violent pornography with regards to violent crime), however it got rejected by her uni's ethics board so it remained unresearched.

However; we can still point out there is basically no correlation using publicly available data: Here is the popularity of each US state searching PornHub for what many would consider violent pornography:

[image]

From [PornHubs BDSM insights](https://www.pornhub.com/insights/bdsm)

And here is the [rape rate per capita](https://www.statista.com/statistics/232563/forcible-rape-rate-in-the-us-by-state/) in the US by state

[image]

That correlation is not strong at all.

- Vermont is most into violent porn. The're about average in sexual crime.
- Oregon is second. They're just above average.
- Mississippi is the least into violent porn, they're also very low in sexual crime.
- Second least is Lousisana. They're just above average in violent crime.
- The most sex crime occurs in Alaska, which is very near average in violent porn consumption.
- Second most is in Michigan, which is about average in violent porn consumption.
- The least sex crime occurs in New Jersey, which is about average violent porn consumption.
- Maine is 4th highest searchers for violent porn, and 8th safest for sexual crime.
- New Hampshire is 3rd highest searcher for violent porn, but a bit safer than average.
- West virginia is 8th highest searcher for violent porn, but safer than the average.

Hong Kong consumes GlobalAverage+61% of violent porn. United States consumes GlobalAverage-13% violent porn. Hong Kong has per capita rape rate thats 48th in the world. The USA has per capita rape rate that 9th in the world. [Your 17 times more likely to be raped in the USA than Hong Kong](https://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/compare/Hong-Kong/United-States/Crime).

This relationship holds true even if [90% of rapes in Hong Kong are unreported](https://www.scmp.com/news/hong-kong/article/1133059/hong-kongs-official-rape-statistics-vastly-lower-grim-reality) and we assume that there are 0 unreported rapes in USA. The USA would still have 1.7 times the sexual crime rate per capita that Hong Kong does.

The correlation is pretty weak. If there's any correlation it may in fact be slightly negative, which would suggest that watching BDSM pornography actually marginally reduces sex crime.

Comment: That last sentence comparing Hong Kong to the USA is comparing crime recorded by the police. Social factors can skew these a great deal; its entirely possible that actual rape is more common in Hong Kong, but it gets recorded by the police much less.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Of course it is. Same with the USA. And everywhere else. [This report](https://www.scmp.com/news/hong-kong/article/1133059/hong-kongs-official-rape-statistics-vastly-lower-grim-reality) estimates it as 90% go unreported. That's still 1.7 times better than the US's reported rate.

Comment: Thank you at least for answering, I shall take some time in reading your answer.

Comment: I was thinking of some other porn sites who keep track of viewers. Do you know some?

Comment: Are you really comparing BDSM with sex crimes or implying that they're correlated?

Comment: @forest Exact opposite. I'm attempting to disprove the correlation between BDSM pornography and sex crimes, refuting the point made in the question. (Sex crimes and consensual BDSM are distinct non-related topics.)

Comment: @Ash It wasn't very clear to me the way it was written.

Comment: @forest The data is basically random noise - if anything it suggests slightly negative correlation. Which would mean that watching BDSM pornography actually marginally reduces sex crime.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my misunderstanding. And just a small nitpick, but "Your 17 times more likely" should be "You're 17 times more likely".